# Solr-cloud - no servers hosting shard: shard1

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have created 6 collections, each collection is having 3 shards and 2 replica (solr version 5.5.0). For a few days my setup was working fine. But after some days when I restated solr started getting error.

Getting error

> PKIAuthenticationPlugin Decryption failed

Server 1:

```
81245736 ERROR (qtp668849042-17075) [   ] o.a.s.s.PKIAuthenticationPlugin Decryption failed , key must be wrong
java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:893)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1249)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1186)
    at org.apache.solr.util.CryptoKeys.decryptRSA(CryptoKeys.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.security.PKIAuthenticationPlugin.parseCipher(PKIAuthenticationPlugin.java:172)
    at org.apache.solr.security.PKIAuthenticationPlugin.decipherHeader(PKIAuthenticationPlugin.java:159)
    at org.apache.solr.security.PKIAuthenticationPlugin.doAuthenticate(PKIAuthenticationPlugin.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.authenticateRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:264)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:196)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
81245736 WARN  (qtp668849042-17075) [   ] o.a.s.s.PKIAuthenticationPlugin Failed to decrypt header, trying after refreshing the key 
81245747 ERROR (qtp668849042-17075) [   ] o.a.s.s.PKIAuthenticationPlugin Exception trying to get public key from : http://SorServer2:8983/solr
org.noggit.JSONParser$ParseException: JSON Parse Error: char=<,position=0 BEFORE='<' AFTER='html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-'
    at org.noggit.JSONParser.err(JSONParser.java:356)
    at org.noggit.JSONParser.handleNonDoubleQuoteString(JSONParser.java:712)
    at org.noggit.JSONParser.next(JSONParser.java:886)
    at org.noggit.JSONParser.nextEvent(JSONParser.java:930)
    at org.noggit.ObjectBuilder.<init>(ObjectBuilder.java:44)
    at org.noggit.ObjectBuilder.getVal(ObjectBuilder.java:37)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.Utils.fromJSON(Utils.java:98)
    at org.apache.solr.security.PKIAuthenticationPlugin.getRemotePublicKey(PKIAuthenticationPlugin.java:202)
    at 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
81245748 ERROR (qtp668849042-17075) [   ] o.a.s.s.PKIAuthenticationPlugin Decryption failed , key must be wrong
```

This issue gets resolved some time when I restart all solr node manually. But after some time I get the same error.

Comment: Maybe more info needed. What have you tried so far? Steps given please?

Comment: I tried - stopped all solr node one by one and restart zookeeper , then start all solr node one by one. Some this with this works but not always. I also tried to -Dpkiauth.ttl=10000 at starting of solr node. This also did not worked. let me know what else I can try?